# Console errors after Wordpress Update 6.1

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, errors, updates, 500-internal-error

I am using Soledad theme with Woocommerce and after updating to version 6.1 I get these errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () post.php:1  

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()  /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1
```

Is anyone having the same issue?

Cheers

Comment: Your first step should be to check with the Soledad development team.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with "WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency" plugin which is related to WMPL. WMPL is having big issues right now with their products and probably are fixing them at this moment.

For example a lot of developers had problems with "WPML String Translation" plugin which caused critical error for websites.